# Version in "./docker-compose.yml" is unsupported. You might be seeing this error because you're using the wrong Compose file version

Tags: docker-compose

Here's my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  a:
    image: tutum/hello-world
  b:
    image: tutum/hello-world

secrets:
  id: my_password
```

If I run `$ docker-compose-up` I get this:

> Version in "./docker-compose.yml" is unsupported. You might be seeing this error because you're using the wrong Compose file version.

My docker-compose version:

```
$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.11.0, build 6de1806
```

What's wrong here? Shouldn't my docker-compose version support v3.1 of the docker-compose.yml specification (according to the [release notes](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases), it does) ?

Comment: what is the version of your docker (not docker compose)?

Comment: Docker version 1.13.0, build 49bf474

Comment: its ```docker-compose``` and not ```docker compose```

Comment: @AbdouTahiri CLI is `docker-compose` but `Docker Compose` is the technology.. https://docs.docker.com/compose/

Comment: Facing the same issue with version `"3.6"`. My docker is `18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24`

Comment: is there any way to check which versions (of docker-compose.yml file) are supported by the installed version of `docker-compose`?

Comment: type "docker compose version",  there is an ambiguity nowadays - "docker-compose" doesn't work anymore in 2.10.2, now it is "docker compose" without the hyphen

Answer (score 121, accepted):

You are doing everything right and it should work. But there was a [bug](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases) in docker-compose 1.11.0 which not recognized file format 3.1 as valid. (3.0 works).

There is already a new release of docker-compose (1.11.1) which includes the bugfix:

> Bugfixes
>
> Fixed a bug where the 3.1 file format was not being recognized as valid by the Compose parser

So I would recommend to upgrade your docker-compose version if you want to use file format 3.1.

At the moment the safest way to upgrade docker-compose is by deleting it and reinstalling it.

```
rm /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Reinstall:

```
curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.11.1/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.11.1, build 7c5d5e4
```

Now there isn't an error anymore on the file format. (I did not test with your .yml).

```
docker-compose up
Starting compose_a_1
Starting compose_b_1
```

Comment: Thanks. For some reason, your curl cmd dose not work for me in ubuntu 16.04. I then updated to the latest docker-compose version following the guide in the official website here. https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/, which is more or less the same as the above. But in curl cmd, the ">" change to "-o".

Comment: Bug also afflicts version 1.8.0; version 1.16.1 is avail and worked perfectly on Ubuntu 16.04. Just fix the version component of the path above, cannot paste it clearly in this comment due to back-quote marks :/

Comment: Don't know the reason but `curl` command doesn't execute. .. says permission denied.

Comment: Those who are facing error in running `curl` command, try this:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/#install-compose

Comment: @DeepakSharma You have to execute the curl and chmod commands as root user (or use sudo)

Comment: @Ivthillo Tried with `sudo` too.. but no luck :( i guess the repo might have diffused. Is same working for you..??

Comment: On my system the path for the binary is `/usr/bin/docker-compose`, so I had to change that in the commands above. Trying to write directly to `/usr/local/bin/docker-compose` caused a "Permission denied" error, even with `sudo`.

Comment: I did a symlink sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose

Comment: "whereis docker-compose" shows the old installation. then that can be replaced by file we get by curl command.

Comment: For the one facing the permission problem, here's a way to solve it https://github.com/circleci/circleci-docs/issues/1323#issuecomment-323620271

Comment: For version 1.26.2 ```sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.26.2/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose```

Comment: Yes, this problem is because of a bug in docker-compose. When I upgraded it with `pip install --upgrade docker-compose` it worked fine.

Answer (score 75):

I have resolved the issue by upgrading docker-compose.

Follwed below steps to upgrade docker-compose in ubuntu16.04

step1:

```
$which docker-compose
/usr/bin/docker-compose
```

step2:

```
$sudo rm /usr/bin/docker-compose
```

step3:

```
curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.20.0/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` -o /usr/bin/docker-compose
```

step4:

```
chmod +x /usr/bin/docker-compose
```

Comment: This worked well for me on Elementary OS Loki (0.4.1).

Comment: Since the version of docker changes frequently look here for installing latest docker version https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/

Comment: The version I was getting from apt-get was 1.17, it was also having this issue (Linux Mint 19). I downloaded 1.24.1 similarly to how these steps lay out, seems to be working. Thanks!

Comment: After deleting it, `sudo apt install docker-compose` Tell me I already have the version, and `docker-compose up` tell me I have no docker-compose installed. Why are you guys not using apt? I have two issues now.

Answer (score 61):

If your file version is 3.7 and you get the following error:

```
ERROR: Version in "./config.yml" is unsupported. You might be seeing this error because you're using the wrong Compose file version. Either specify a supported version (e.g "2.2" or "3.3") and place your service definitions under the `services` key, or omit the `version` key and place your service definitions at the root of the file to use version 1.
```

Here is the solution:

1. Remove current binary `sudo apt-get remove docker-compose` OR `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/docker-compose`
2. Download the binary `sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v1.29.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose`. You can find the current latest [version here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/release-notes/) (1.29.1 as of writing).
3. Allow execution `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose`
4. Remove old link `sudo rm /usr/bin/docker-compose`, make new link `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose`

I hope this resolves the issue.

Comment: you might want to go to check the latest version at https://github.com/docker/compose/releases , at this time, the version is 1.27.4

Comment: I fixed it up now, updated version to latest.

Comment: At the time of 2022, you need to write the letter 'v' before the version. like: `sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.14.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose`

Answer (score 10):

To get the latest version of docker-compose :

```
sudo apt remove docker-compose
curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.28.4/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` -o /usr/bin/docker-compose
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/docker-compose
```

Answer (score 7):

If using **linux/ubuntu**, This is maybe obvious but be careful you run as root e.g.

```
docker-compose -v
```

Gives

```
docker-compose version 1.8.0, build unknown
```

vs

```
sudo docker-compose -v
```

Gives

```
docker-compose version 1.17.1, build 6d101fb
```

Also make sure docker-compose and docker-machine are up to date as **@lvthillo** states

Comment: This should be the right answer. I'm in Ubuntu, I had to use SUDO command for working

Comment: sudo docker-compose -v gives me docker-compose version 1.8.0, build unknown

Comment: Is that with sudo ?

Comment: -1. Sudo is bad. Here's an alternative: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user

Comment: Nice add, although I wouldn't say its "bad". Feel free to edit the answer to include that as an addition.

Answer (score 3):

try uninstall old version and reinstall.

```
sudo apt remove docker-compose
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.22.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
reboot
```

should print out

```
docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.22.0, build 1719ceb
```

Comment: Why reboot the machine just because you downloaded a file?

Comment: Worked for me but reboot was unnecessary

Answer (score 2):

I had done `docker-compose --version` prior to implementing lvthillo's solution and I was still getting outdated versions showing up.  It turned out I needed to flush the hash list my bash shell was holding onto.  `hash -r` ... hope that is useful for someone else

Answer (score 2):

We cant able to tell you without watching the particular error
firstly check it with by running this command

`docker build .`
when you got the error then search it in google 
in my case it was the permission error when i tried it with sudo it worked.

Hope it will help you

Answer (score 2):

As @Ivthillo said, you need to upgrade to version 1.11.1.
You should first remove the current version file

```
sudo rm -f ${which docker-compose}
```

then install 1.11.1 version

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.11.1/docker-compose-$(uname -s|sed -e 's/\(.*\)/\L\1/')-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

and give execution permission to it

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

**Notice**: for installing latest version you can use below command

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/latest/download/docker-compose-$(uname -s|sed -e 's/\(.*\)/\L\1/')-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this issue, however how I've came around it, was to downgrade the version that my `docker-compose.yml` file was using.I've realized that every **docker compose** version release has a limit of a docker-compose file version they can't exceed. In my case, I was using the docker version release of 1.25.0, that is not greater than 3.7 docker compose file version. I had to downgrade from 3.9 to 3.7

Answer (score 1):

Here are steps to install latest docker compose into user space:

```
rm /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
wget -O /usr/local/bin/docker-compose https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/latest/download/docker-compose-linux-x86_64
ls -l /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
docker-compose --version
```

Answer (score 0):

**On osx 10.12.6 sierra**

Steps for v1.22 or higher

I had a specific issue/incompatibility where I did not want to completely upgrade docker. I am stuck currently on docker 17.06.0-ce-mac18. So I merely wanted to upgrade docker-compose and nothing else.

My steps:

- Identify location of docker-compose: `which docker-compose`
- Identify docker-compose version: `docker-compose --version` = `docker-compose version 1.14.0, build c7bdf9e`
- backup previous docker-compose?: `mv /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/local/bin/docker-compose-bak`
- replace with 

  `` curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.22.0/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > /usr/local/bin/docker-compose ``
- if you need to determine the latest version just check https://github.com/docker/compose/releases and replace version above with latest.
- verify version: `docker-compose --version` = `docker-compose version 1.22.0, build f46880f`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by making sure my **new code** aligns with **the rest of the code**. It appears as it needs to have a certain format and if it's misaligned in regards to the rest of the code it won't see the 'Valid top-level sections for this Compose file are: version, services, networks, volumes, secrets, configs, and extensions starting with "x-".'

Answer (score 0):

Try with "sudo"

```
sudo docker-compose up
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to uninstall docker or remove anything.
If you get an error similar to the following when running `docker-compose up`:

`Version in "./docker-compose.yml" is unsupported. You might be seeing this error because you're using the wrong Compose file version. Either specify a supported version (e.g "2.2" or "3.3")...`

you can just modify the version specified in your docker-compose file

```
version: '3.1' # change to version '3.3'

services:
  a:
    image: tutum/hello-world
  b:
    image: tutum/hello-world

secrets:
  id: my_password
```

and run docker-compose up again.

Answer (score -1):

The issue was caused by too low version of docker-compose = 1.25.0, which is unfortunately the highest version Ubuntu supports on any of their current releases, including focal (20.04LTS), groovy (20.10) and hirsute.

Upgraded docker-compose the official docker/non-Debian-way:

```
$ sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.27.4/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
$ sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
$ which docker-compose
/usr/local/bin/docker-compose
$ docker-compose -v
docker-compose version 1.27.4, build 40524192
```

[Reference](https://github.com/linkedin/datahub/issues/2020#issuecomment-736850314)